# How do I set system.commandline to be case insensitive

Tags: .net, command-line

The Microsoft provided system.commandline does most things, but I've not found a way to tell it to always ignore case - I'm hacking around it by forcibly lowercasing the first word and anything starting with "-" from the arguments..

Is there any way of forcing it to be case insensitive?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this is of interest https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/issues/1667

Comment: yeah - found that while googling - but it was 2017, and there's been no response since.  I'm actually expecting at this point there's not built in - but hoping someone has come u with a better hack than mine - I tried subclassing "option" but you can't override the HasAlias function, so that doesn't work.